# How can I stop IIS from redirecting every request to remove the .aspx ending?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, friendly-url

I created a new project (Web Application, C#, ASP.NET 4.5) in VS 2015 and I do not want my site to use FriendlyURLs at all. I would like to see .aspx in the browser when I visit my site.

I removed FriendlyURLs using the NuGet package manager. I also removed all the references and the Redirect code from the project. The site, though, still continues to redirect each request from /Default.aspx to /Default.

Is there a way to stop IIS or VS from doing that?

Comment: what do you have as your startup page in IIS as well as the project. what if you launch your application in `IISExpress` do you still see the .aspx in the pages when navigating..? also take a look at `Routing`

Comment: Just to make sure, have you removed `routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();` from your `RouteConfig.cs`?

Comment: @MethodMan, @sjokkogutten thanks for your help. I removed `RouteConfig.cs` and all the references to routing I could find. I believe it is a rogue dll that does not want to clear up. I got it to work well for new master pages, but not for the original master page. It does the same thing on IIS express (10) and a physical IIS server (7.5)

Comment: at least you are on to the right path, track.. I had an issue like that before but make sure that you don't have any references / assemblies that reference that as well.. also check out your `Global.asax` file too.. you may have the following code `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` in there and your `App_Start` folder has `RouteConfig.cs` file as well.. comment out this line like I have done in mine `//routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();`

Answer (score 1):

This could potentially be a caching issue with your browser and `IIS`.

If you've used a project with [Microsoft.ASPNet.FriendlyUrls](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls) and it's removed the `.aspx` extension and you've opened another `Webforms` project Chrome will cache the removal of the `.aspx` extensions.

You will need to clear the cache if this is indeed the issue (you can try using incognito mode first to see if this is actually the issue).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for me was to create a whole new website (on filesystem in my case) and copy all the files from the "corrupted" site to this new one. No changes were done to the original files and the problem disappeared. 
This is not a good solution, but I did not found any other :-(

For my opinion this behavior is caused by previous 301 redirecting in browser. I use MSIE, but it cache 301 probably forever. Using another browser can by solution for this or find the way, how to clear redirection cache.